# testing membership provider

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, testing, membership-provider

I want to try testing membership provider. Question is that I want to test for example CreateUser method inside memb. provider, this method should insert data inside database, test if is inserted and if that True rollback transaction (delete user from db, leave db as is was).

Can someone provide sample code hints fot that test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the membership provider has a unique constraint on the username and the DB won't allow the insertion of duplicate entries in the table if an existing username is inserted.

If you want to test it, simply run an inset statement against the user table using an existing username.